# Spring Redirect and delete ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a controller:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public ModelAndView loginGet (@ModelAttribute(value = "MESSAGE_CUSTOM") String message) {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null || authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {

            return new ModelAndView("/login");

        } else {

            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");

        }
    }
```

When I do a redirect, in this case the ModelAttribute is redirected too:

```
http://localhost:8080/?MESSAGE_CUSTOM=
```

How do I prevent the ModelAttribute from being redirected?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public ModelAndView loginGet (@ModelAttribute(value = "MESSAGE_CUSTOM") String message) {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null || authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {

            return new ModelAndView("/login");

        } else {

        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/");
        redirectView.setExposeModelAttributes(false);

        return new ModelAndView(redirectView);

        }
    }
```

http

```
http://localhost:8080/
```